# matrix with 2 dimensional array js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array list which contains two colors.

```
const data = ['red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue']
```

and i want to achieve the matrix like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3weU.png) that represent the table below.

```
┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
│ 'red'  │ 'red'  │        │        │        │        │
│ 'blue' │ 'blue' │        │        │        │        │
│ 'red'  │        │        │        │        │        │
│ 'blue' │ 'blue' │ 'blue' │ 'blue' │ 'blue' │ 'blue' │
│ 'red'  │ 'red'  │ 'red'  │ 'red'  │ 'red'  │ 'blue' │
│ 'blue' │ 'blue' │  'x'   │  'x'   │ 'red'  │ 'blue' │
│ 'red'  │ 'red'  │  'x'   │  'x'   │ 'red'  │ 'blue' │
│ 'blue' │ 'blue' │ 'blue' │  'x'   │ 'red'  │ 'blue' │
│ 'red'  │ 'red'  │ 'red'  │  'x'   │ 'red'  │        │
│ 'blue' │  'x'   │  'x'   │  'x'   │ 'red'  │        │
│ 'red'  │        │        │        │        │        │
│ 'blue' │        │        │        │        │        │
┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

This what i've done so far(code below). So can anyone or someone point me a direction?, because currently im lost right now for the logic just to achieve the table above.

```
const road = []

const fill = total => Array.from({ length: total }).map(() => 'xxx')

const test = e => {
  let row = null

  if (!road.length) {
    return road.push([e])
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < road.length; i++) {
      if (road[i].includes('xxx')) {
        const sub = road[i][0] // first entry

        if (sub && sub === 'xxx') {
          row = i
          break 
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (row) {
    // logic here!
  } else {
    const currRow = road.length - 1
    const currCol = road[road.length - 1].length - 1

    if (road[currRow][currCol] === e) {
      if (road[currRow].length > 5) {
        road.push([...fill(road[currRow].length - 1), e])
      } else {
        road[currRow].push(e)
      }
    } else {
      road.push([e])
    }
  }
}

data.forEach(e => {
  test(e)
})
```

current result;

```
┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
│ 'red'  │ 'red'  │        │        │        │        │
│ 'blue' │ 'blue' │        │        │        │        │
│ 'red'  │        │        │        │        │        │
│ 'blue' │ 'blue' │ 'blue' │ 'blue' │ 'blue' │ 'blue' │
│  'x'   │  'x'   │  'x'   │  'x'   │  'x'   │ 'blue' │
┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: could you write an expected result instead of this meaningless table?

Comment: @Ifaruki the meaningless table is the one that i want to achieve.

Comment: @el5 there doesn't seem to be a pattern in the expected output, care to explain

Comment: i want to know what the expected output should look like, is this an array, or an matrix or anything else? A table like this is meaningless because we do not know how the  output should look like, everybody could interpret this table on his own way and make his own version